# Remove link, keep text in jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'd like to remove some links from the back-end of my WordPress dashboard with the same domainname, but keep the text. I've tried the following code but it didn't seem to work at all. How do i get this to work?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('a').filter(function() {
              return this.href.match(/DOMAINNAME/); 
      }).attr('href', '');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove an element but retain its content you can use the `replaceWith()` method. You can also use the 'Attribute contains' selector to make targeting the elements more simple. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('a[href*="DOMAINNAME"]').replaceWith(function() {
    return this.innerText;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#foo">This link will be kept</a><br />
<a href="https://DOMAINNAME.com/">This link will be removed</a><br />
```